# How can i stop repeating my code in this situation?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple game with trivia API and here's my html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid row">
        <div class="col question">
            <h5>Question</h5>
            <h2 class="text-primary">0/5</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col score text-right">
            <h5>Score</h5>
            <h2 class="text-primary">0</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container bg-light">
        <h1 class="display-3" id="questions"> What is the answer to this question? </h1>
        <div class="info-question">
            <div class="choice" id="1"></div>

            <div class="choice" id="2"></div>

            <div class="choice" id="3"></div>

            <div class="choice" id="4"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/trivia/trivia.js"></script>
</body>
```

My Javascript code:

```
let question_one = document.getElementById('1')
let question_two = document.getElementById('2')
let question_three = document.getElementById('3')
let question_four = document.getElementById('4')
fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({
        results,
    }) => {
        question_one.textContent = `Question 1: ${results[0].question}`
        question_two.textContent = `Question 2: ${results[1].question}`
        question_three.textContent = `Question 3: ${results[2].question}`
        question_four.textContent = `Question 4: ${results[3].question}`

    });
```

I'm trying to for loop through the result questions but don't know how and where to start? 
I appreciate every answers!

Comment: using numbers for ids is typically not the best practice.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Only after the code works, which this doesn't!

Comment: @Mast, unfortunately the PO's actual question is about improvements, not about fixing it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt That doesn't excuse the bad recommendation. Please, Code Review gets enough poor questions already.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
<div class="info-question">
        <div class="choice ques" id="1"></div>

        <div class="choice ques" id="2"></div>

        <div class="choice ques" id="3"></div>

        <div class="choice ques" id="4"></div>

    </div>
```

then in js:

```
let questions = document.querySelectorAll('.ques');
fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({
        results,
    }) => {
        questions.map((ques, I) => {
            ques.textContent = `Question ${i+1}: ${results[i].question}`
        }

    });
```

make sure that you should have a unique class which is only used in questions, in this case `ques`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function that works as a template. You can define your html structure in your js file.

```
function getQuestionHTML(question, index){
  return `<div class="choice" id="${index}">${question}</div>`
}

const questionsInfoEl = docuement.querySelector('info-question');
fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({
        results,
    }) => {
      const questionHTMLList = results.map((data, index) => getQuestionHTML(data.question, index));
      questionsInfoEl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', questionHTMLList.join(''));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic results you may prefer to not initialize your `div` that contains results but just a container:

```
const containerEl = document.getElementById('choices-container');

fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({
        results,
    }) => {
        results.map((result, idx) => {
          const node = document.createElement('div')
          node.textContent = `Question ${idx + 1}: ${result.question}`
          node.classList.add('choice')
          containerEl.append(node)
        })
    });
```

Also update html:

```html
 <div class="info-question" id="choices-container">
   <!-- Remove divs, just initialize container -->
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and js file will look like this after changes.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid row">
     <div class="col question">
         <h5>Question</h5>
         <h2 class="text-primary">0/5</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col score text-right">
         <h5>Score</h5>
         <h2 class="text-primary">0</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container bg-light">
     <h1 class="display-3" id="questions"> What is the answer to this question? </h1>
     <div class="info-question"></div>
 </div>
 <script src="/trivia/trivia.js"></script>
```

```
let questions = document.querySelector('.info-question');
fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({results}) => {
        let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        results.forEach((data,index)=>{
            let div = document.createElement('div');
           div.textContent = `Question ${index+1}: ${data.question}`;
           div.className = 'choice';
           div.id = index;
           fragment.appendChild(div);
        })
        questions.appendChild(fragment);

    });
```